# Did Swami Vivekananda speak this statement? Please give the location where he says so

Tags: vivekananda, reference-request

When More and more people start thinking for themselves, start placing reason over faith, science and logic over irrationality and blind belief and superstitions, that will be the day when Hinduism will succeed.

Comment: not in his Complete Works.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda Sir did he make such statements anywhere else??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly those words but he said pretty much the same thing about all religions in a speech delivered in England, 1896.

> [Complete-Works > Volume 1 > Lectures and Discourses](https://www.ramakrishnavivekananda.info/vivekananda/volume_1/lectures_and_discourses/reason_and_religion.htm)
>
> #### Reason and Religion
>
> (Delivered in England)
>
> ...
>
> The physical sciences are better equipped now than formerly, and religions have become less and less equipped. The foundations have been all undermined, and the modern man, whatever he may say in public, knows in the privacy of his heart that he can no more "believe". Believing certain things because an organised body of priests tells him to believe, believing because it is written in certain books, believing because his people like him to believe, the modern man knows to be impossible for him. There are, of course, a number of people who seem to acquiesce in the so-called popular faith, but we also know for certain that they do not think. Their idea of belief may be better translated as "not-thinking-carelessness". **This fight cannot last much longer without breaking to pieces all the buildings of religion.**
>
> The question is: Is there a way out? To put it in a more concrete form: Is religion to justify itself by the discoveries of reason, through which every other science justifies itself? Are the same methods of investigation, which we apply to sciences and knowledge outside, to be applied to the science of Religion? In my opinion this must be so, and I am also of opinion that the sooner it is done the better. **If a religion is destroyed by such investigations, it was then all the time useless, unworthy superstition; and the sooner it goes the better. I am thoroughly convinced that its destruction would be the best thing that could happen. All that is dross will be taken off**, no doubt, but the essential parts of religion will emerge triumphant out of this investigation.
>
> ...

Comment: Sir I have a doubt. Once Swamiji says Smritis and Puranas are products of limited intelligence. Somewhere he says I want to revive Manu and Yajnavalkya.But he knows they do have verses which are little too harsh. Now how to reconcile all his statements!??

Comment: Good question, you should gather all those contradictions (with references) and ask a separate question about it. Any followers of Vivekananda on this site should be able to answer...

Comment: Ok sir. Could you please tell your views

Comment: I've only read some of Vivekananda's lectures so not sure where he talks about 'reviving Manu and Yajnavalkya'. If you can point me to the specific speech I can take a look. Also, if you ask a separate question about it, others also can try to resolve any contradiction. I too find Vivekananda a bit confusing sometimes, in one speech he's defending Hinduism, other times he's very critical of it. Maybe his views have evolved over time and that is what is causing the confusion to a reader like you & me. Also, you don't need address anyone as 'sir' on this site. Everyone is equal here.

Comment: Sir may I ask you what all scriptures you read? Please dont mind me asking like this. I follow Neo Vedanta of Swami Vivekananda and as above answer you said I have problems with majority of Scripture. I just curios to know your views. I saw your answer if I am correct you quoted Garikapati Garu so you are also a Telugu person like me. Could you please tell me

Comment: Sir no I appolozize. I refered you as Sir only. I always refered you as sir. You cant be anti Hindu when you write and quote from Hindu Dharma book . I even read and upvoted such answes. Even recently. When you wrote on Hinduism and Pornography. You have lot of knowledge and rationality and honesty which many of Hindus may not like. I appolozize from bottom of my heart that I hurt you. No Sir, I refered you as sir only.

Comment: I asked a Vedic Scholar Kiron Krishnan(Very famous) He is also of same opinion Puranic Gods are different from Vedic Gods. But ultimatly result is same. End way is Brahman. Isnt it? But I dont think Samhitas support Advaitha?? Sir Flaws in Chaganti Garu ?? and Intrested changed?Please tell. There is another rationalist like you - Rami Sivan on Quora. You might know him! Very popular!
Sometimes I believe in

Comment: I am deleting all my nonsence messages and apologizing from deep of my heart Please accept my sincere appolozizes.

Comment: Ok sir thanks a lot  for agreeing and also forgiving me 